# How to concatenate a character to every element of an Array (Java)

Tags: java

I am purely novice in Java. Yesterday I was working on a home work. I had to split a string character by character and store those letters in an array. Then print this array. *(DONE)*

Then concatenate a single character (let's say `'a'`) with the every element of that array and print the results. *(NOT DONE)*

And at-last concatenate all those elements and create a string and print it. *(NOT DONE)*

```
String name = "Rocky";
int i;
int size = name.length();
char strings[] = new char[size];
for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    strings[i] = name.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(strings[i]); // 1st output is done
}
```

The second output (concatenated char) should be:

```
Ra
oa
ca
ka
ya
```

The third output (single concatenated string) should be:

```
Raoacakaya
```

Finally I have done this and it works after-all its my homework maybe its not all up to standard. Thanks all for for replying.

```
    String a="a";                   
    String name="Rocky";
    String temp="";
    int i;
    String array[]=name.split("");
    String array2[]=new String[name.length()+1];
    for(i=1; i<=name.length();i++)
    {
        System.arraycopy( array, 0, array2, 0, array.length );
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(i=1; i<=name.length();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array2[i]+a);
        array2[i]=array2[i]+a;
    }
    for (i=1; i<array2.length;i++)
    {
        temp=temp+array2[i];
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(temp);
    }
    }
```

Comment: SO is not for homework help.

Comment: I know that. Sorry for asking help regarding HW. But i was unable to do it myself that's why asked for help. Will not do this again.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to use `int size`, just use `name.length()` instead. As for the outputs, you can do it this way:

```
char c2 = 'a';
String all = "";
for(char c : strings)
{
    String s = String.valueOf(c) + String.valueOf(c2);
    System.out.println(s); // 2nd output
    all += s;
}
System.out.println(all); // 3rd output
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get you right. If so, this should do the trick:

```
public static void homeWork() {
    final String name = "Rocky";
    final char toAdd = 'a';
    char[] array = name.toCharArray();
    String concatenated = concatenate(array, toAdd);
    System.out.println("Concatenated : " + concatenated);
}

public static String concatenate(char[] array, char toAdd) {
    StringBuilder buidler = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : array) {
        String toAppend = String.valueOf(c) + String.valueOf(toAdd);
        System.out.println(toAppend);
        buidler.append(toAppend);
    }
    return buidler.toString();
}
```

You run through the array with a for each loop and append
all characters with the letter you put in "toAdd".
Print the result for every loop and print the end result,
after the method returns.

Output:

```
Ra
oa
ca
ka
ya
Concatenated : Raoacakaya
```

Comment: You can't simply add a `char` to a `String` as it doesn't have a default `.ToString()` function and you have to convert it to `String` first.

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd output:

```
char a = 'a';
String all = "";
for(char c : strings)
{
    String s = String.valueOf(c) + String.valueOf(a);
    System.out.println(s);

}
```

For 3rd output:

```
char a = 'a';
String wholeString= "";
for(char c : strings)
{
    String s = String.valueOf(c) + String.valueOf(a);
    System.out.print(s);
    wholeString+= s;
}
```

System.out.println(wholeString);

Comment: `and at-last concatenate all those elements and create a string and get an output` where does your solution for part 3 concatenate the String? You're just printing independent substrings to the console, not a single string, as requested.

Comment: Yes tom its my mistake. Here either will have to append with StringBuffer or '+'